# ExpandableListView click events not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a 'ExpandableListView' in my Navigation drawer and the click listeners are not working, once i open the Navigation Drawer and click on any parent element of 'ExpandableListView', it only closes the drawer. Can someone guide me where i might be doing wrong.

**Source Code of ExpandableListView**

```
private void populateExpandableList() {
    prepareMenuData();
    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, groupIcons, groupIconsSelected);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    ...
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ...
                    break;
                ...
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            switch (groupPosition) {
                case (2):
                    ...
                    break;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });



public void prepareMenuData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    groupIcons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    groupIconsSelected = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    groupIcons.add(R.drawable.cust_home);
    ...

    listDataHeader.add("Home");
    ...

    // Subcategories -- News
    List<String> news = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), new ArrayList<String>());
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), new ArrayList<String>());
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), news);
    ...

}
```

**Source Code inside onCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        userIv = header.findViewById(R.id.user_iv);
        loginTv = header.findViewById(R.id.login_tv);
        userNameTv = header.findViewById(R.id.username_tv);
        emailTv = header.findViewById(R.id.email_tv);
        navHeaderLl = header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_ll);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        getSubcatFromServer();
        setUpNavHeader();
        populateExpandableList();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }
```

Comment: ExpandableListView can expand/collapse without setting any listener but **OnGroupClickListener()** blocks this action if it is not coded properly. Try without OnGroupClickListener(). Hope it helps!

Comment: @I_A_Mok, yes...what the problem was..i was having an overlay which i was using on a particular condition, so even if that overlay used to be hidden, it was blocking the click events of ExpandableListView(i'm not sure why), then i used a seperate layout for that and used that overlay as a popup...now everthing is working fine.